# Is there a name for highly aggressive non-violent people?

Tags: social-psychology, abnormal-psychology

I know an individual who has incredibly aggressive mannerisms including snatching things, raising voice and speaking with a very aggressive tone of voice.

However, since this person is completely non-violent - would never raise a finger against anyone, no-one ever *considers* them aggressive - and nor does this individual, as their response is always "I'd never hit anyone".

Is there a word or psychological term which describes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passive-aggressive, hostile, officious?

Their response is also biased, we may say we'll never do something.. it's still possible we will though given the right circumstances.